# Put Gamecenter in it's own class

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, game-center, game-center-leaderboard

I started coding a few weeks ago and now want to implement GameCenter in a little game I am working on.

I began by following this [tutorial](https://youtu.be/FTm3fdQyiUk) on YouTube and everything worked fine when I had the [GC functions](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B763wDJVXUR_bW1yWTA4N252T2M/view?usp=sharing) in my *ViewController: UIViewController* class.
For the sake of an organised code I'd prefer to put them into their own *GameCenter: GKGameCenterControllerDelegate* class, which I tried to do but miserably failed.

What I did is, that I added a Swift file in Xcode in which I created a new class for the GC functions. I'm currently calling them in my *ViewController* with something like:

```
GameCenter().authenticateLocalPlayer()
```

Now I'm not sure how to edit this part of the code to make it work, I think it got something to do with the ViewController but I must admit that I don't understand it completely:

```
func showLeaderboard() {

    var vc = ViewController().view?.window?.rootViewController
    var gc = GKGameCenterViewController()
    gc.gameCenterDelegate = self
    vc?.presentViewController(gc, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

I already changed

```
var vc = self.view?.window?.rootViewController
```

to

```
var vc = ViewController().view?.window?.rootViewController
```

but am not sure what to do with

```
gc.gameCenterDelegate = self
```

I think I either need to change *self* to something like my *ViewController()*, or that I have to do something with the protocols of my classes, or both.

Can anyone help me put the GC related functions into their own class?
Thank you in advance. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made it easier for myself and just switched to [Easy Game Center](https://github.com/DaRkD0G/Easy-Game-Center-Swift).